# Generating multiple files of shuffled integers for a given range c++

Tags: c++, random, file-io

I am trying to generate multiple files (say 100) of shuffled integers for a particular range (for eg: 1000, 10000 etc). This is the code I have tried so far

```
// random_shuffle example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::random_shuffle
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <ctime>        // std::time
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand, std::srand
#include <fstream>

// random generator function:
int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}

int main(){
   std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );
   std::vector<int> myvector2;
// For creating 10 different shuffled files
   for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
// set some values:
      for (int i=1; i<=10000; ++i) myvector2.push_back(i);

// using built-in random generator:
      std::random_shuffle ( myvector2.begin(), myvector2.end() );

// using myrandom:
      std::random_shuffle ( myvector2.begin(), myvector2.end(), myrandom);

// print out content:
       std::cout << "Data Shuffled:";
// put content in out file
      std::ofstream f2("out.txt");
       for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector2.begin(); it!=myvector2.end(); ++it)
       f2<< *it <<'\n';
     }
return 0;
}
```

The file 'out.txt' gets overwritten and I end up with just one file. How can I create multiple files which have different set of shuffled integers in each file?

Thank You

Comment: Does it matter that you are writing random numbers to the files? If not, you will need to reduce your code by that to get closer to the core of the problem. Also, please make the code complete, so that others can take and compile it. And format it, too, so others can read and understand it. As it stands, your question is off-topic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt . Can you help me understand why my question sounds off-topic?

Comment: @NivethaMahalakshmi You should read the help section on "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the sake of providing an educational example, this is probably how i'd approach it.

Comments are inline. This code uses some c++14 features.

Note that The entire operation is expressed in terms of standard algorithms. This is the best way to make the code portable, maintainable, correct and gives the compiler the best possible opportunities for optimisation.

```
#include<random>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>

// generate a vector of all integers in the set Is...
template<int...Is>
auto initial_vector(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    return std::vector<int>({ Is... });
}

// defering to template expansion function allows the compiler to populate the vector from a compile-time
// computed data table. Totally unnecessary, but I find it pleasing.
auto initial_vector()
{
    return initial_vector(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 10000>());
}

int main()
{
    auto eng = std::default_random_engine(std::random_device{}());

    // make our initial vector
    auto data = initial_vector();

    // for each data set...
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
    {
        // shuffe the data...
        std::shuffle(std::begin(data), std::end(data), eng);

        // create a filename from th index of the data set
        auto strm = std::ofstream("data" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt");

        // copy the data-set to the file, encoded as newline-delimited strings representing decimal integers
        std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int>(strm, "\n"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same file name each time std::ofstream f2("out.txt");

try to use different name in each time for example out1.text, out2.txt, ...

you can get this form j in the for loop

```
std::ostringstream stringStream;
stringStream << "out"<<j<<".txt";
std::string fileName= stringStream.str();
```